# Making Kafka.js external dependency using webpack in node as a commonjs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, dependency-injection

I'm trying to make kafkajs external dependency (move out from webpack bundle) with this config:

```js
externals: {
    kafkajs: 'kafkajs',
    redis: 'redis'
}
```

Dependencies:

```js
  dependencies: {
    ...
    "kafkajs": "^1.12.0",
    ...
  }
```

But I'm getting error "Cannot find module":

```js
{
  "error": "Initialization has failed due to: Error: Cannot find module 'kafkajs'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)\n    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)\n    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)\n    at Object.<anonymous>"
}
```

I tried clearing the cache, saving the dependency again and with different externals configuration:

```js
externals: [
    "kafkajs",
    {
       Kafka: {
        commonjs: ["kafkajs", "Kafka"], 
    }
]
```

Thanks ahead for any guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are bundling your node.js app, it is better to mark as external all the node_modules, there is a lib for that, [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals).

```
npm install webpack-node-externals --save-dev
```

```js
//webpack.config.js

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
    ...
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    ...
};
```